# Facebook latest page content in the share dialog

Tags: sitecore-client, caching

Is there something out of the box to clear cache for Facebook share? 
I have to clear the browser cache for the share dialog to take the latest updated content.

Is there something in Sitecore that does this for me to make the facebook share easier?

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing OOTB built into Sitecore for this. To clear the Facebook cache you have 2 options:

#### Manual Cache Clear

You can manually clear the cache by going to the [Facebook Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and enter the URL you want it to scrape. This forces Facebook to clear the cache and get the site data again.

#### Clear Via API

You can use the [graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update) from Facebook.

The API endpoint to clear it is:

```
POST /?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&scrape=true
```

The response from this endpoint will be a JSON object that contains all the information about the object that was scraped (the same data returned when the Object ID is read from the Graph API).

You could create a ribbon bar button to call this API for the currently selected item in the content editor.